# I cannot display images in a UWP GridView

Tags: c#, gridview, data-binding, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm working on a UWP Desktop books application, and I can't display book cover images in a GridView.
Questions:

1. Is GridView the best control for this or should I use a ListView?
2. Below are the XAML and Code Behind I'm using. If you can tell me what's wrong, I really appreciate it.

   ```
             <GridView Name="gdvLibrary" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Margin="10,0,20,3" Width="auto" Height="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
                        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate x:Name="ImageTextDataTemplate" x:DataType="local:Book">
                                <StackPanel Height="280" Width="180" Margin="12" >
                                    <Image Source="{x:Bind Cover.Source}" Height="180" Width="180" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                                    <StackPanel Margin="0,12">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Title}"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Author}" Style="{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageTextBaseMediumBrush}"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <ItemsWrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="10" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                </GridView>


        // Set the path to the app's books folder.
        string path = @"D:\_BOOKS";
        Image img = new Image();

        // Get the folder object that corresponds to this absolute path in the file system.
        StorageFolder folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(path);

        if (folder != null)
        {
            foreach (StorageFolder sf in await folder.GetFoldersAsync(Windows.Storage.Search.CommonFolderQuery.DefaultQuery))
            {
                img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(sf.Path + @"\cover.jpg"));

                string strAuthor = sf.DisplayName.Split(" - ")[0];
                string strTitle = sf.DisplayName.Split(" - ")[1];

                WCRVariables.Books.Add(new Book
                {
                    Cover = img, 
                    Title = strTitle,
                    Author = strAuthor,
                    Percentage = 0,
                });
            }

            this.gdvLibrary.ItemsSource = WCRVariables.Books;

        }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use **GridView** control, because GridView works better for items that have images as their focal point. Besides, to bind the Image.Source property, you need to construct a BitmapImage instance like the following.

Xaml code:

```
 <Image Source="{x:Bind Bitmap}" Height="180" Width="180" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
```

Code behind:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Book> books { get; set; }
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            books = new ObservableCollection<Book>
            {
               
                 new Book(){Title="English",Bitmap=new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/1.JPG"))},
                 new Book(){Title="Math",Bitmap=new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/2.JPG"))}
            };
            gdvLibrary.ItemsSource = books;
        }
    }

    public class Book
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public BitmapImage Bitmap { get; set; }
      
    }
```

**Update:**

If your image file is located in a user folder, you could use Storage Api to get the StorageFile object, then use [StorageFile.OpenAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile.openasync?view=winrt-20348) method to get stream, finally set this stream as the source of Image. Please refer to the following code.

```
BitmapImage Bitmap= new BitmapImage();
var storageFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(path);
using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
{
    await Bitmap.SetSourceAsync(stream);
}
img.Source= Bitmap;
```

Note that you need to declare `broadFileSystemAccess` capability in Package.appxmanifest like the following. Besides, you need to grant the permission in **Settings** app for this uwp app, access is configurable in **Settings** > **Privacy** > **File system**.

```
<Package
  ...
  xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap">
...
<Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="broadFileSystemAccess" />
</Capabilities>
```

Comment: Simple <Image Source="{x:Bind Uri}" would work too

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys, but they didn't work. When I change the image path to one located in the Assets folder everything works. But I need to use a user folder.

                         Code that works:
CoverB = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Square150x150Logo.scale-200.png")),

                         Code that doesn't work:
CoverB = new BitmapImage(new Uri(sf.Path + @"\cover.jpg")),

Comment: @JoseAfonso I have updated my answer, please check it.

Comment: @AryaDing-MSFT, thank you for everything,. Worked perfectly.